# Does WordPress charge for pointing to my custom domain

Tags: wordpress

I have brought a domain name from godaddy - let's say example.com

I have a wordpress blog eg:- example.wordpress.com. Now I want to use custom domain(example.com) for the blog. I have heard it charges me money for custom domain. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

Yes they will.  The cost varies, generally between $13 and $25 per year.

If you already own the domain and wish to add it to your Wordpress site then it will cost $13 per year.

If you want to register a new domain and add it your Wordpress site then the cost starts at $18.

You can also purchase Private Registration at an additional cost of $8 per year.

It is important to note that depending on what top level domain you choose the price will change. e.g. a `.com` domain will cost you $18 where as a `.me` domain will cost you $25.

A full list of prices for domains can be found on [this support page](http://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/)

> - Registering a domain through WordPress.com starts at $18.00 per domain, per year (see below for a detailed price list)
> - Domain owners are required to share their contact information. The $8.00 Private Registration upgrade will protect your identity and hide
>     your contact information.
> - Adding a domain you already own costs $13.00 per domain, per year.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the blog to appear that it is really hosted on btechgirls.com then yes, it will cost you money. It looks like $12/year since you already own the btechgirls.com domain.  See: http://en.support.wordpress.com/domain-mapping/

For no additional money you should be able to redirect the btechgirls.com to btechgirls.wordpress.com through GoDaddy.  When a user is looking at the blog it will still be at btechgirls.wordpress.com but you can use btechgirls.com for promo, links, etc.

Comment: I successfully did this with my blog through WordPress.  I just had to redirect the domain in the GoDaddy tools.

Answer (score 0):

There is one alternative, which is getting your domain provider to do a URL frame. I don't know if GoDaddy does this (namecheap does), but you get an HTML page that embeds the Wordpress site.

- The plus side: The URL bar always reads example.com
- The downside: The URL bar always reads example.com (so people can't easily link to an individual blog post.)